# Costumizar DB Grid com dados do webservice

Tags: delphi, web-service, delphi-xe8

Estou criando um sistema simples para testar o funcionamento do Delphi com WebService REST, o primeiro teste é uma busca de dados no banco que neste caso esta funcionando tudo certinho, só que, quando os dados são carregados na DBGrid a visualização fica horrível, gostaria de saber se tem como customizar a visualização destas informações como alterar o nome e o tamanho das colunas.

DBGrid:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, fica muito ruim com esses campos gigantes pra pouca informação e esses títulos da coluna ficam com o nome que chega do WS.

Eu utilizei a ferramenta REST Debugger para fazer essa comunicação do WS com a Grid.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em algum evento após os dados serem carregados (talvez no final do evento do botão Pesquisar) faça um *for* das colunas do grid e verifique pelo dataset o tamanho do campo (ex. string(200)), aí calcule o width da coluna, faça por exemplo 200 * 3 e vc terá um tamanho aproximado apropriado ao tamanho do campo.

Comment: Normalmente, quando o `DBGrid` é preenchido em tempo de execução, ele próprio define a propriedade `Width`de cada coluna. Diante isto, alguns ficam com o tamanho muito grande mesmo, em alguns casos é até desnecessário. 

Minha sugestão: Já deixe os campos no `DBGrid` configurados para que, ao receber o retorno do REST, apenas preencher e não configurar.

Comment: @LucasdeSouzaCruz meu problema é justamente tentar já deixar configurado, já que eu não consigo adicionar Fields no TFDMemTable para conseguir configurar fields na grid, há não ser que exista outra forma de configura-la, pois eu só conheço utilizando um Query e um DataSource (FireDac).

Comment: Bem, se você clicar duas vezes sobre o `Grid` você consegue adicionar os campos que você precisa exibir. Configurar ele é fácil, é só informar o `Title` e o `FieldName` e pronto.

Comment: @LucasdeSouzaCruz então, o problema é que quando eu clica no FieldName da erro: Cannot open dataset, provavelmente eu tenho que adicionar um novo componente ou configurar alguma coisa no TFDMemTable, mas de qualquer forma eu consegui configurar certinho da forma que queria utilizando a dica do Andrey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em algum evento após os dados serem carregados (talvez no final do evento do botão Pesquisar) faça um *for* (laço de repetição) das colunas do grid e verifique pelo *dataset* o tamanho do campo (ex. string(200)), aí calcule o *width* da coluna, faça por exemplo 200 * 3 e vc terá um tamanho aproximado apropriado ao tamanho do campo.

```
for i:=0 to dbgrid.columns.count -1 do
begin
  dbgrid.columns[i].width := dbgrid.datasource.dataset.fieldbyname(dbgrid.columns[i].fieldname).size * 3
end;
```

Claro que o código acima pode ser melhorado, ele é apenas uma ideia de como fazer. Podes ainda ver o tipo do campo (integer, varchar e etc) e alterar o valor de multiplicação.

Comment: Complemento para a Resposta: Ideal aplicar esta lógica no `onDrawCell` que é um loop automático do Grid.

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Não vejo a necessidade de colocar no `onDrawCell`, porque as colunas não variarão seu tamanho de acordo com o conteúdo do campo, mas sim de acordo com o tamanho no banco, então se executar apenas uma vez logo após a abertura do `dataset` já é o suficiente. Entendo que sua sugestão é válida caso a largura da coluna seja condicional ao conteúdo do campo. Concorda?

Comment: Concordo, a sugestão foi em relação a `Em algum evento após os dados serem carregados`. No `onDrawCell` fica elegante por ser automático e SEMPRE executar no carregamento/recarregamento, não sendo necessário a estrutura extra de repetição `for` (este é meu pensamento lógico para diminuição de código ;D). De qualquer forma o meu +1 já esta dado ;D

Comment: Ah legal, entendi seu objetivo ao colocar no `onDrawCell`, realmente diminui o código, mas ao meu ver consome recursos do sistema sem necessidade pois ele será executado cada vez que o grid for *redesenhado*.. mas ta valendo. Obrigado pelo +1 e pela sugestão. ;)